# Return a value if it EVER occurs in a column and ignore all others

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that has multiple duplicates, and I need to find out if any of the rows of data also have a value in an adjacent cell and ignore any other values.

Below is an representative example of the Data Set I am working with:

[image: Click for Data Set]

The list contains multiple colours and products that have been made that colour.
I want to then have a result return if there is ever an eraser in that colour. A summary would look as follows:

[image: Click for Result Table]

So the formula that would be in the result column looks at all the times a colour is mentioned and if an eraser is made in that colour, then the result is "Y" otherwise the result is "N"

I've tried so many things and nothing seems to be doing this...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The formula would need to work on more than just 3 colours in the long run but there are only ever 5 possible items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` nested inside an `IF` statement. 0 returns **FALSE**, anything else returns **TRUE**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: While this works really well, I am now having the issue that when I apply this to a larger dataset, it takes a huge amount of time to process. Is there maybe a faster way of getting the same result?

Comment: How large of a data set? You can do a pivot table and filter by `Eraser`

Comment: around 50k lines. Pivot doesn't do the job. I'm trying to create some automation and the pivot would require some manual intervention

Comment: This equation shouldn’t be that demanding. My gut feeling says the performance issue lies elsewhere. If I’m wrong, You are at a classic cross roads of usability vs performance. A pivot would simply require the click of a refresh button